# Discord.py send error msg if member don't have role

Tags: bots, discord.py, roles

Hey I'm a beginner to discord.py and need some help.

I am making a discord bot and I have a command that only members with the "Staff" role can use but if you don't have the role I want a command that sends an embed that says "Staff role is a requirement to use this command!". But I don't know how to make it, I have tried a little bit of everything but nothing works =/

This is what I have so far

```py
# Moderator Commands List
@commands.has_role('Staff')
@bot.command(name='help_mod')
async def help_mod(context):
    my_embed = discord.Embed(title="Moderator Plugin", color=0xFFC71C)
    my_embed.add_field(name="Ban a member from the server", value="``?ban [member] (optional reason)``", inline=False)
    my_embed.add_field(name="Temporarily ban a member from the server", value="``?tempban [member] [duration] (optional reason)``", inline=False)
    my_embed.add_field(name="Mute a member in the whole server", value="``?mute [member] (optional reason)``", inline=True)
    my_embed.add_field(name="Temporarily mute a member in the server", value="``?tempmute [member] [duration] (optional reason)``", inline=False)
    my_embed.add_field(name="Kick a member from the server", value="``?kick [member] (optional reason)``", inline=False)
    my_embed.add_field(name="Unban a member", value="``?unban [member]``", inline=False)
    my_embed.add_field(name="Unmute a member", value="``?unmute [member]``", inline=False)
    my_embed.set_thumbnail(url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/765665083082407976/767502481922981928/ModHammer.png')
    my_embed.set_footer(text="Work in progress, these commands are not in function yet.")
```

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this solution later, works perfect.

```
from discord.ext.commands import MissingPermissions
   
 

@helpm.error  # <- name of the command + .error
        async def helpm_error(ctx, error):
            if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRole):
                error_role = discord.Embed(description="Staff role is a requirement to use this command!", color=0xf30000)
                await ctx.message.channel.send(embed=error_role)
```

Comment: Is there a reason to un-accept my answer and post your own (based on mine), improved one? That's not really how this works.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in the error handler:

```py
@bot.command(name='help_mod')
@commands.has_role('Staff')
async def help_mod(ctx):
   # ...


@help_mod.error # <- name of the command + .error
async def help_mod_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRole):
        await ctx.send("Staff role is a requirement to use this command!")
```

[Here's](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html?#error-handling) an introduction to error handling

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I wanted and it works perfect!

Comment: Remember to accept the answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

Alternatevly to the answer above, you can also do the following:
Remove the `has_role` check, instead check in your code wether the user has the demanded role.

```
@client.command(name='help_mod')
async def help_mod(context):
    staff_role = discord.utils.get(context.guild.roles, id = role_id) # Insert the role id here
    if staff_role in context.author.roles:
        # Your Code
    else:
        # Send error message
```

***Filtering the role by ID also ensures that your code still works even if the name of the role got changed.***